# building Rserve

Tags: r, autoconf, rserve

I'm trying to build Rserve.

Steps so far:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/s-u/Rserve.git
$ cd Rserve
$ aclocal -I m4
$ autoconf
$ ./configure
```

fails with

```
[...]
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for library containing SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations... -lssl
checking whether threads are desired... yes
checking for working threads support... configure: error: cannot find install-sh, install.sh, or shtool in "." "./.." "./../.."
```

after symlinking my install-sh into the directory

```
$ ln -s /usr/share/automake-1.14/install-sh install-sh
```

./configure dies with

```
checking for working threads support... configure: error: cannot run /bin/bash ./config.sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The developer of Rserve told me to

```
$ sh mkdist
```

**`*facepalm*`**